# Is there a way to define an HTTP filter and have it provide a bean or data as a @RequestScoped item?

Tags: quarkus

Lets say I have a filter that implements `ContainerRequestFilter`, and I want it to interrogate some headers/params and build some sort of object. I then want that object available to the rest resource function (GET/POST/etc).

How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RESTEasy Reactive, You can create your own `@RequetScoped` beans with a CDI producer.

Here's an example:

```
@Singleton
public class MyProducer {

    @RequestScoped
    @Produces
    SomeClass doSomething(HttpHeaders headers) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```